# Shared data classes in microservice architecture with Spring and Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, microservices

Suppose you have two microservices talking to each other, both share data classes as contracts. While you dont want to duplicate all contracts in every microservices project, whats the best way to share them?

As is see it, there are only two options:

- Duplicate shared contracts, while also duplicating code
- Compile a first party library and import it

Comment: Have you checked Spring Cloud Contract? It provides you some tools to keep contracts between microservices without the need of a POJO library https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract

Comment: I'm using 'contracts' as a term for data classes here, this might have needed some more definition. So, the Spring Cloud Contract is not solving the case as i see it, as it is providing mocking in a test environment for endpoints.

Comment: You would normally keep some sort of separate commons project where you version your DTOs and add this as a dependency to each of your microservice projects. Duplicating code is always bad and I would strongly advise you against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team had the same scenario some time ago and we decided for a variant of your second point.
 We used Maven Multi-Module Project, so that one Microservice produced the library, which was then imported by the 2nd Microservice.

Maven Multi-Module Project is explained here:
https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module

Comment: Yes, this is what we did then, only difference is Gradle Builder, but this is also available here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to do `project1 > project2` dependency because it might change in the future and you'll end up having to refactor the whole thing.

What I'd do is to create a shared library that's published to an internal Nexus or artifactory, then you can just add this as a dependency to your project so you'll have something like this:

```
library > project1
library > project2
```

Another idea to consider is to use something like [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) if you are only sharing the data transfer objects. This has the additional advantage of versioning and forward compatibility.